# How do i get value of label

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<div id="abc">    
    <table id="qtytable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="QTY" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

How do I get value of label?

```
$("#abc).find("#qtytable label:first");
```

Returns length 0. What is an alernative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#<% QTY.ClientID %>').text();
```

Remember ASP.NET renders controls with different client names than server ID names.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#<%=QTY.ClientID%>').html()
```

will give the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#<%=QTY.ClientID%>').text()
```

.text() should get you the value

api here:

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<%= QTY.ClientID %>').html();
```

or even using javascript :

```
document.getElementById('<%= QTY.ClientID %>').value;
```

Comment: .value() is undefined in jQuery. (and also, labels don't have value)

Comment: we should use .text instead of .html as .html is meant to get all the html inside a html tag.